# how to do multiple transactions in hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

1. lets assume we have 2 tables , table A and table B.
2. I want to insert a row in table A and then in table B.
3. If something goes wrong while inserting in table B then I also want to roll back the insertion of row in table A

what I have done is explained in below diagram
[image]

Comment: Picture is ok for showing a diagram. But put your comments and question as text and not as a picture. It is barely readable and obviously it cannot be found by searching on the site.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to stick to this architecture, which is not the best one, you would need to start a new transaction when you are using the B DAO.

Mark the method that is doing the insert with:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void insertB(B b) {
    // insert B
}
```

Now in A DAO add this to the method that inserts A:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public void insertA(A a) {
    // insert A
}
```

Now when an exception occurs in B DAO, that transaction will be rolled back and then the exception will be propagated to A DAO and will make that transaction rollback also (unless you will catch the exception, then there will be no rollback)